# How to draw smooth path with NSBezierPath

Tags: cocoa, nsbezierpath

I am draing path with NSBezierPath currently:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect 
{
    [[NSColor blueColor] set];
    [path stroke];
}
```

But the line seems pretty ugly(not smooth)

Then I googled for some solutions and I got this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect 
{
    NSGraphicsContext *graphicsContext;
    BOOL oldShouldAntialias;

    graphicsContext = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];
    oldShouldAntialias = [graphicsContext shouldAntialias];
    [graphicsContext setShouldAntialias:NO];

    [[NSColor blueColor] set];
    [path stroke];

    [graphicsContext setShouldAntialias:oldShouldAntialias];
}
```

But for me, noting changed, I still got the ugly path.

Any suggestion?

Thanks for answer.

Here's the details:

1. Create a cocoa application (not document-based)
2. Create a new class "StretchView"

#### StretchView.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface StretchView : NSView {

    NSBezierPath *path;
}

-(void)myTimerAction:(NSTimer *) timer;

@end
```

#### StretchView.m

```
#import "StretchView.h"

@implementation StretchView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame 
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        path = [[NSBezierPath alloc] init]; 
        NSPoint p = CGPointMake(0, 0); 
        [path moveToPoint:p]; 
        myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                   target:self
                                                 selector:@selector(myTimerAction:)
                                                 userInfo:nil
                                                  repeats:YES];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect 
{
    NSLog(@"drawRect");

    [[NSColor blueColor] set];
    [path stroke];
}

-(void)myTimerAction:(NSTimer *) timer
{  
    NSPoint p = CGPointMake(a, b); //a, b is random int val
    [path lineToPoint:p]; 
    [path moveToPoint:p]; 
    [path closePath];

    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
} 

-(void)dealloc
{
    [path release]; 
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

3.Open the Interface builder and drag a "Scroll view" to the main window
4.Choose the "Scroll view" and set the class "StretchView" (in class identity window)

Comment: Please attach a screenshot illustrating the problem.

Comment: Also, please let us know where this drawRect method is located (is it just a simple view, or something like an NSTableView?) and the code for setting up the path.

Comment: You probably want to turn anti-aliasing *on*, not *off*...

Answer (score 0):

Using `lineToPoint` will just create straight zigzaggy lines, even as part of a bezier path. If by "smooth" you mean "curvy", then you should probably check out `curveToPoint` instead. Also, note that these "toPoint" methods already move the point, no need to `moveToPoint` unless you intend to move to a different point than where your line ended.